MIDI Realtime support in Blender
Exciting times. The defacto addon I use for MIDI is AddRoutes. Last code release was approx 2 years ago. After many Blender iterations https://github.com/JPfeP/AddRoutes no longer works beyond Blender 4.0. Also download and website link no longer work.
Luckily new kid in town @slashv did pull request https://github.com/JPfeP/AddRoutes/pull/25 - but that didn't get actioned so @slahv did right thing ( IMHO ) and forked to https://github.com/slashv/AddRoutes. With stable download link of https://github.com/slashv/AddRoutes/releases/
I personally think that real time MIDI plus Blender is quite exciting . I am in touch with slashv and hopefully simplify interface in world of Geometry Nodes.  Also add some documentation and sample Blender files as MIDI can be bit of a git to setup sometimes.

Hello and welcome! Please note that this is not a regular forum, but a Q&A website. Please be so kind as to read the help pages carefully. If you have a specific question regarding the use of Blender, ask it and someone will be happy to help you.

Sorry, but where exactly is the question you want to be solved?
